# For My the "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events" is disabled

Tags: tasks, activities, taskrelation

I want to relate several contacts to mys task.
And i know that fot rhis i should enable the "Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events"  checkbox .

[image]

However it is disabled in my sandbox .
And TaskRelation object is not visible in my Dev Console.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated .
Thank you.

Comment: how long ago did you enable this in the sandbox manually or is this a refresh from production where it is enabled? If you upgraded manually, did you receive an email saying it completed successfully? Your screenshot shows `feature enabled`, but the checkbox is not checked which is the difference I immediately noticed with my own testing in a sandbox.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I did not enable it.
I started working on this project a month ago.
And no one at project knows anything about it.
Is there any chance that it was enabled and it  expired in some way ??

Comment: Is it activated in production? Is your execute anonymous code just a SOQL query or anything specific?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I have the same situation in production.  
It is not just SOQL query. I tried to create TaskRelation object for Contact an Task records.